# Fluctuation-Dissipation Relation for Quantum Phase Transitions

Tags: quantum-field-theory, statistical-mechanics, field-theory, phase-transition, fluctuation-dissipation

I am looking for a formulation for the fluctuation-dissipation relation connecting the correlation related quantities with the thermodynamic functions at the quantum critical point.

**The fluctuation-dissipation relation at classical critical points**

In the classical case there is (e.g. described by [Hankey and Stanley 1972](https://doi.org/10.1103/PhysRevB.6.3515)) a relation between the general homogeneous functions (GHF) derived from thermodynamic potentials e.g. the free energy $f$,
$$\lambda f(t,H)=f(\lambda^{a_t}t,\lambda^{a_H}H)$$
and the GHF for the pair-correlation function,
$$\lambda C_2(t,H)=C_2(\lambda^{b_t}t,\lambda^{b_H}H,\lambda^{b_r}\vec r)$$
in the vicinity of the critical point ($t=T-T_c=0$, and conjugate field $H=0$).

The fluctuation dissipation relation relating the structure factor $S(t,H,q)$ at $q=0$ with the susceptibility:
$$\chi_T(t,H)=\int \text{d}\vec r C_2(t,H,\vec r)=S(t,H,\vec q=0)$$
This leads to relations between the $a_t,a_H$ with the $b_t,b_h,b_r$ exponents.

**Question: Does this relation translate straightforwardly to QPT**

I am now interested in a similar relation for quantum phase transitions with tuning parameter $\Gamma$ (e.g some transversal field), conjugate field $H$ and temperature $T$. In the vicinity of the quantum critical point ($\Gamma=0$, $H=0$ and $T=0$) the scaling forms for the free energy and pair correlation are given by,
$$\lambda f(\Gamma,H,T)=f(\lambda^{\tilde a_\Gamma}\Gamma,\lambda^{\tilde a_H}H, \lambda^{\tilde a_T}T)$$
and,
$$\lambda C_2(\Gamma,H,T,\vec r)=C_2(\lambda^{\tilde b_\Gamma}\Gamma,\lambda^{\tilde b_H}H, \lambda^{\tilde b_T}T,\lambda^{\tilde b_r}\vec r) \ .$$
I am especially interested in the $T=0$ case and simple $\phi^4$ phase transitions.

Is there a similar connection for the quantum case? And how would it look like?

I would guess it could be something like the following. Is that maybe correct?:
$$\chi(r,H,T=0)=\int \text{d}\vec r C_2(\Gamma, H, T=0, \vec r) = S(\Gamma, H, T=0, \vec q=0)$$